# Regexp_Replace multi occurance of a character with same number of replacements in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I need a regular expression to replace 0 with O in a string,only 0 if its linked to a word.
eg :

```
R0OSEVELT => ROOSEVELT
100 RO00SEVELT => 100 ROOOSEVELT
0RANGE10 => ORANGE10
PALT00OO = PLATOOOO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with sql, here's the code i could come up with.

```
REPLACE
   (search_string,
REGEXP_SUBSTR
   (search_string,
    '([[:alpha:]]+|^|[[:space:]])0+([[:alpha:]]+|$|[[:space:]])'
   ),
TRANSLATE
   (REGEXP_SUBSTR
       (search_string,
        '([[:alpha:]]+|^|[[:space:]])0+([[:alpha:]]+|$|[[:space:]])'
       ),
    '0',
    'O'
   )
   )
```

Here's the output. It works for your input cases. Maybe I've missed some other possibilities.

```
R0OSEVELT --> ROOSEVELT
100 RO00SEVELT --> 100 ROOOSEVELT
0RANGE10 --> ORANGE10
PALT00OO --> PALTOOOO
RO00SEVELT 100 --> ROOOSEVELT 100
RANGE10 --> RANGE10
RANGE0 --> RANGEO
```

Comment: Awesome Noel..Thanks a lot..seems to solve all the options..Great Work!! Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: It looks like only first occurrence of 0s is getting replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what happens to a single zero standing on its own but:

```
sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]])?0([[:alpha:]])/\1O\2/g; s/([[:alpha:]])0([[:alpha:]])?/\10\2/g'
```

will do the part of the job you did specify.
The first substitute command replaces zeros by the letter 'O' if it is between two alphabetic characters or at least followed by an alphabetic char, ie word beginnings. The second does the same with word endings.

Comment: How do I implement in SQL statement? I didn't get it